# Show weekday in taskbar windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Trying to add "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy" (or "dddd, ...") in the windows taskbar clock results by not showing the date at all. My taskbar is by right side.
Is it an official issue? How can I add the weekday to the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a shorter format, like `ddd, d/M/yy`.

Comment: Nice! According to this I've found, that resize of taskbar helps.